# Angular innerHTML adds unwanted chars

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a menu that should look like this in the end:

```
<ul nz-menu>
    <li nz-submenu nzTitle='Parent'>
      <ul>
        <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Item 1">
          <ul>
            <li nz-menu-item>Option 1</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>Option 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I have to do it in a programmatic way and for some reason I cannot do it with ng-template so I want to create it first and then insert it with `innerHTML`

If I do something like:

```
 @ViewChild('test') viewElement: ElementRef | undefined;

    const menu=`<ul nz-menu>
    <li nz-submenu nzTitle='Parent'>
      <ul>
        <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Item 1">
          <ul>
            <li nz-menu-item>Option 1</li>
            <li nz-menu-item>Option 2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  `;

    if (this.viewElement)
      this.viewElement.nativeElement.innerHTML = menu;
```

What I get in the HTML is:

```
  <ul nz-menu="">
  <li nz-submenu="" nztitle="Parent">
    <ul>
      <li nz-submenu="" nztitle="Item 1">
        <ul>
          <li nz-menu-item="">Option 1</li>
          <li nz-menu-item="">Option 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I get those nasty **=""** after the properties where there should be clean **nz-menu**, **nz-submenu** and  **nz-menu-item**.
Even if I go the other way in the HTML with

```
<div [innerHTML]="menu"></div>
```

I still get the same result.
Needless to say this does not render as it should that's why I ask the more knowledgeable people here for help.

How can I overcome this issue?

I'm using ng.ant.design if anyone is wandering.

Comment: Is nz-menu an angular directive? If so, this will not work like this.

Comment: Yes it is. How can I do it then?

Comment: I’m not completely up to date with the post-ivy way of doing this. This is the ‘old’ way which might no longer work with newer versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576727/angular-compile-and-create-components-at-runtime

Comment: Maybe this is a better link.. seems to work withIvy as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67108489/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-dynamically-compile-component-in-angular-11